# Label max/min values in a scatterplot in ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a large data frame where I want to do a scatterplot where only the max/min values are labeled.

```
some_df <- data.frame(
   "Sport" = c(1:5), 
   "avg_height" = c(178, 142, 200, 135, 182), 
   "avg_weight" = c(66, 61, 44, 77, 100))
```

I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
some_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(avg_weight, avg_height, label = Sport)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(avg_height == max(avg_height)))
```

But get errors telling me that `avg_height` is not found.

I have also tried with the `geom_text`

```
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(avg_height=max(avg_height), as.character(Sport), '')), 
          hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

with error for `Sport` not found.

So I can either label all or none, but with the large data.frame it will be impossible to read. If I can colour only the max/min values it would be fine too. 
I have experimented with making a new column and trying to join with new variables like below, but it haven't helped me.

```
maxw <- some_df %>% summarise_each(Max = max(avg_weight))
maxh <- some_df %>% mutate(summarise(Max = max(avg_height)))
```

The scatterplot I want is with labels only for the max and min of both avg_heigt and avg_weight.

Comment: Interesting enough I get edited for writing the code on one row this time. Last time I got edited for putting it  on several rows (which I prefer as it's easier to read). I t's hard to do it right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the data points of the extreme values of both `avg_weight` and `avg_weight` are supposed to be labeled with the value of `Sport`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
some_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(avg_weight, avg_height, label = Sport)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  geom_label(data = some_df %>% 
               filter(avg_height %in% range(avg_height) | avg_weight %in% range(avg_weight)),
             nudge_x = 1)
```

creates

[image]

#### Edit

The OP has [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903441/label-max-min-values-in-a-scatterplot-in-ggplot2-r/53904120?noredirect=1#comment94652993_53904120) to label the points with the highest and lowest BMI `avg_weight / (avg_height/100)^2` as well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# append BMI column to dataset
some_df <- some_df %>% 
  mutate(bmi = avg_weight / (avg_height/100)^2) 
some_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(avg_weight, avg_height, label = Sport)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  geom_label(data = some_df %>% 
               filter(
                 avg_height %in% range(avg_height) | 
                   avg_weight %in% range(avg_weight) |
                   bmi %in% range(bmi)
               ),
             nudge_x = 1)
```

The resulting  chart is the same as above.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this helps a lot. Lets say I want to label two more points. The pints that have the highest and lowest bmi i.e. `avg_weight / ((avg_height/100)^2). ` Can I put that command in there as well?